# How to process payments with credit cards through Paypal from Argentina

Tags: php, paypal, credit-card

I am new to Paypal integration and cannot find how am I supposed to make it. My requisites are the following:

- Company registered in Argentina
- Users should be able to buy without having to create a Paypal account with a credit card
- The integration should not be easily tampered with

With those (I thought) simple requirements I spent many hours and couldn't find a solution that applied.

This is what I found out:

- Payments REST API, should not be used for credit card payments

  > Important: The use of the PayPal REST /payments APIs to accept credit
  >   card payments is restricted. Instead, you can accept credit card
  >   payments with Braintree Direct.

  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/
- Braintree Direct (the method to integrate credit card payments with full customization is not supported in Argentina) https://www.braintreepayments.com/country-selection
- NVP and SOAP API Reference (old Paypal API to integrate payments) is no longer supported.

  > Important: This integration method is Deprecated as of January 1, 2017. For 
  >   new integrations, see the PayPal Express Checkout Integration Guide.

  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/
- PayPal Express Checkout Integration is horrible, seems insecure and prone to tampering if used only client side, and though I found a way to make it work more securely with a server-side payment generation *I couldn't find a way for it to pay without having a Paypal account*.
  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/ 
  and 
  https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

So I am left with no option to integrate credit card processing through Paypal for a business in Argentina. Before giving up I would like to know if somebody knows of a way to make this integration work.

Comment: "I couldn't find a way for it to pay without having a Paypal account." - that's by design.

Comment: Out of curiosity, tried Stripe?

Comment: BTW, if you want to keep users on your site without sending them to PayPal, you want "PayPal Website Payments Pro" where PayPal acts like other Merchant services like Authorize.net, but you have to pay for it: https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro (the link is for the US, but I assume it's available in Argentina)

Comment: @Dai Paypal Website Payments Pro is not available in Argentina. Only US, UK and Canada :(

Comment: For the downvoters, please add a comment why you think the question is wrong so I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Payoneer is also an option. Paypal isn't the only thing out there.

Comment: Thank you @DevOnix but Paypal is a customer requirement not a decision of mine.